# C# comma usage in a ternary operator

Tags: c#, if-statement, conditional-operator

Is there any analogy like in C that the comma operator can be used in C# as well as following.

```
 templateCode = myBoolFlag ? ((smsNotification.NewNumber = request.NewNumber), "NEWCARDSTR")
                                       : request.NewCardStatus == "L" || request.NewCardStatus == "S" 
                                           ? "STRING1" 
                                           : "STRING2";
```

Comment: I strongly suspect that using an `if` statement would lead to more readable code here. Using a side-effect just in one path of a conditional operator seems like a bad idea to me.

Comment: You can use a local function and invoke that, if you absolutely want side effects in your expression. Of course the angels will weep if you do that; there's a reason C# has no comma operator (along with most other C-like languages other than C++). Nested ternary expressions aren't so hot either. There is no tax on semicolons.